# Finding a formula for a $C^{\infty}$ 1-form $\omega$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let me elaborate more. Suppose that $(U, x^1, ... , x^n)$ and $(V, y^1, ... , y^n)$ are two charts on $M$ with a nonempty overlap $U \cap V$. Then a $C^{\infty}$ 1-form $\omega$ on $U \cap V$ has two different local expressions:

$\omega = \sum a_j dx^j = \sum b_i dy^i$. Find a formula for $a_j$ in terms of $b_i$.

Any help would be great. A complete solution is ideal. I'm studying for an upcoming exam in my Differential manifolds class. Thanks!

Comment: Use the chain rule for differentials: $d x^j = \sum \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i} d y^i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exam must have passed a while ago now, but hopefully this is still helpful.

In general, how do you find the local expression for a $1$-form $\omega$? The coefficient on a  basis element $dx^j$ in the local coframe is whatever you get when you apply $\omega$ to the corresponding basis element $\partial/\partial x^j$ in the local frame. So:
\begin{align*}a_j&=\omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i} b_i dy^i\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i} b_i\left(dy^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\\
&=\sum_ib_i\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}
\end{align*}